# Overriding style of a component from other library is not taking affect (React)

Tags: css, reactjs

I used a DataTable of carbon react component:

```
import './Comp.css'
import { DataTable} from "carbon-components-react";
```

and I'm trying to override the width and height css properties:

Comp.css:

```
/*@import "../App.css";*/

.bx--data-table-container{
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

But it's not taking affect!

If I change it from DevTools of the browser it works (the ones with red arrows):

[image]

Comment: So it doesn't help to add more specificity to it?
`.container > bx--data-table-container` or `bx--data-table-container.override-height`. Don't forget to add !important after the property, otherwise the selectors will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible in your use case to write inline with the component, I don't know if its the best way but I want to say it will work

Comment: I tried already that way:  <DataTable
                                isSortable
                                style={{maxWidth: 'none'}} but didn't help too!

Comment: did you try it in line with the important added as well?

Comment: Just tried, not helping :~    style={{maxHeight: 'none !important'}}

Comment: hmmm that's stumped me for now